# Porting PHP function to Ruby

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3

So as you all probably know already, there is no facebook API for Rails 3 (not well-supported/documented anyway). I am wondering whether porting these PHP API to ruby is a good idea or not. What I mean by porting is writing my own php function that uses FB API and use the output as the ruby input. Is this a good idea? Impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also take a look at [fbgraph](http://github.com/nsanta/fbgraph). It uses the new [FB Open API Stream](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Using_the_Open_Stream_API) and it is build for Rails 3.

Answer (score 1):

It is experimental, but it is working. Facebooker-rails3 on [github](http://github.com/funkensturm/facebooker-rails3).